# Meaning in Context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the difference in meaning between these two questions:

> who are you?

and

> what are you?

Answer (score 0):

> Who are you?

Asks for the person's name or identity.

> What are you?

Depending on the context, what is asked for can vary quite a bit. So, it is not possible to give one general answer without further context. But possible answers could be: "I am a human.", "I am a woman.", "I am a doctor."...

Comment: Then there are questions like, "What are you, crazy?" (which is essentially the same as, "Are you crazy?")